# When does AWS Lambda create ENI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, cold-start

I know lambda will create ENI (which in turn will create a longer cold start) if it wants to access resources in VPC. However, I wish to know ***when*** does the lambda function create ENI?

Is it on the container's initialization? (which the developer has no control of)

or is it when we start a connection (running `db.Connect()` or something like it) with other resources e.g. RDS

Answer (score 1):

ENI create every cold start.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

> When a Lambda function is configured to run within a VPC, it incurs an additional ENI start-up penalty. This means address resolution may be delayed when trying to connect to network resources.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the complete picture.  Some cold starts certainly do, but the formula `Projected peak concurrent executions * (Memory in GB / 3GB)` given on that same page implies that the ENI is associated with the host VM rather than the container, suggesting that multiple concurrent invocations of the same function -- which of course means multiple containers -- might nevertheless be on the same host and thus leverage an already-allocated ENI.  Worst case, you're correct.  Best case, it may be less often than this.

Comment: So, it's not something that we can control? e.g. even if I only return a empty response from the lambda inside a vpc, it would still create ENI? (I know if I just want to return empty response I don't need to bind it to VPC, but I'm just curious)